# wso2 esb saxon ee configuration

Tags: wso2, saxon, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use the **XSLT Mediator** but when taking a value, i'd like to apply a custom groovy function to it.
For example:

```
<script language="groovy">
  def myfunction(value) {
     return "A B C";
  }
</script>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <urn:item>
      <urn:productName>
         <xsl:value-of select="myfunction(PRODUCTNAME)"/>
      </urn:productName>
   </urn:item>
</xsl:template>
```

The error i'm getting is:
*net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named myfunction()*

As i read, Saxon HE (the default xslt processor in wso2esb) is not able to call extension functions but Saxon PE or EE does.

I follow steps detailed here (http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/how-to-replace-saxonhe940wso2v1jar-in.html) but same error.

**My question is:**
Is there another way to do what i need? How can i know that wso2 esb is loading properly Saxon EE?

Thank you very much for your help!

Regards,
R.

=====================================================

**Solved!**

- Follow @Carpentidge steps to install Saxon EE in WSO2ESB.
- Following @MichaelKay link, i used Java to do what i need

First, download common-lang3.jar.zip and copy the .jar file into repository/components/lib.
Then, modify the xslt as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="pn" select="CSITPRODUCTNAME"/>
   <urn:item>
      <urn:productName>
         <xsl:value-of select="lang:unescapeHtml($pn)" xmlns:lang="java:org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils"/>
      </urn:productName>
   </urn:item>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you both for your help @Carpentidge and @MichaelKay

Answer (score 0):

Saxon doesn't support extension functions written in groovy, and it doesn't recognize the `<script>` element in a stylesheet file. Saxon's mechanisms for defining extension functions are described here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will take a look to that link.

Answer (score 0):

The manual for replaxing saxon you reference is not for the ESB :) To replace saxon for the esb, put the `saxon9ee.jar` in the `ESB_HOME\lib\endorsed` folder and remove the saxon_HE file. Put the license file in the `ESB_HOME` folder (you can request a temporary one from saxonica.com) and restart the ESB. 
I had some difficulties using 9.6.0 so I'd say use 9.5.1.
http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml

Comment: Thanks! I will try your way and, as Michael wrote, i think i will need to try with a Java or .Net script instead of groovy. I really don't know if it is possible to do something like i was looking for.

Comment: I tried your instructions but no luck. I still have the same error: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named myfunction()
Another clue? how can i check if Saxon EE was loaded? Dosgi doesn't help me... Thanks.

Comment: Ah but now you are coming back to the fact that Saxon EE might not support the function you mention as Micheal Kay explained below/above. I am just responding to your question 'how can I check if saxon was loaded' with the observation that the manual you reference is not correct. There is nothing directly indicating that it is loaded, but I noticed loads of errors when it was NOT loaded. So you can remove the .jar and see if you notice a difference during ESB startup. (if not you probably have the saxon HE file somewhere around still..)